# Decrypt secret message from logical test

Tags: cipher

My friend is studying Maritime technologies. He was given a logical test, where there was the following question:

> A paper message was found lying on the street near shop AKVAPLUSS with such content:
>
> NFITJMDSMNFCVHMNMBSERFYWVELUEKCQSJ
>
> Decrypt the code to discover the secret message.

- The test ended a week ago, we are simply interested in the way it can be decrypted, because all the ways we tried didn't work.
- The question was 4th in the test if it helps.
- Finally the teacher answered the e-mail, but he didn't give the answer to the puzzle, however he gave a hint (how we should find out that ourselves I don't know):

  > Place under the message the word "akvapluss"

**EDIT**: Clarified puzzle and found out that teacher was made unique puzzles for each student, and my friend is from

> Latvia

Comment: Did the test allow computer access? in other words, should this be solvable by hand?

Comment: What were the other questions? Did any of them require knowledge of maritime technologies? Or is this just a test of general critical thinking?/

Comment: If the test ended, why not ask the proctor for the solution?

Comment: @Kevin Test was general, for testing logic ad thinking. Other questions included also mathematical puzzles. I wrote that he studies Maritime technologies because I thought that message encoded there may have maritime theme/words.

Comment: @IanMacDonald Unfortunaly, he doesn't have courses with that teacher now and teacher doesn't answer e-mail. I thought that while waiting response from teacher it would be good to share puzzle.

Comment: @IvoBeckers Yes, they could use anything. Also, there was around 20 minutes for each question.

Comment: I'm not sure if the first 3 questions can give clues on this one since it is the  4th. Sometimes it is based on continuity from previous questions.

Comment: @Mekalikot I think first question are not connected with this one. All of them are math problems.

Comment: I'm guessing that maybe it cannot be solved in English. You are from Latvia, right? Any chance that the message can be in Latvian?

Comment: @cinico No chance for Latvian, it could be in Finnish, because friend is studying in Finland.

Comment: Akva Pluss is a bathroom furnishing store in Latvia

Comment: could akvapluss be the key??

Comment: Frequency analysis doesn't work. M appears 4 times. E, F, N, S appear 3 times each. C, J, V appear 2 times each and the rest appear only once.

Comment: If you need to place text under it, most likely it's encoded with Vigenere cipher.

Comment: This might be too random, but I see some similarity between the words 'maritime' and 'akvapluss'. The first half of both is water-related, while the second half is a mathematical operation having an extra or missing an s.

Comment: If it is Finnish, it could be a word already ;)

Comment: This reminds me of the Enigma Machine, specifically the naval enigma machine. The Cipher Text being in all capital letters with non-repeating characters also supports this theory. Perhaps the date of the test could be used to find out which rotors and plug board connections were used from a naval code book.

Comment: @MrPublic not enigma. enigma had no 'J' only 'I'

Comment: @Jasen I believe you are confused. The Naval Enigma machine most definitely had an 'I' and a 'J'. In fact, all Enigma Machines included 'I' and 'J' in its Rotors, Plugboard, and Keyboard.

Comment: It seems Vigenere cipher but i cannot find any solution in english

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Pretty sure the decrypted text is:

> mumstaiztmugurastirtveikalsttobago - obtained as a Vignere using the key provided (but shifted one forward; a = 1, b = 2)

Which according to google translate is:

> Latvian

Unfortunately I couldn't decipher the actual message, not knowing the language, but putting spaces in random places did give me some English when put through the translator.

Comment: Actually, if you replace letters "t" by space, you get normal sentence in that language so I wil consider that you cracked it.

Answer (score 0):

Tried using the Vigenere cipher with Finnish alphabet (I googled for it). If I did not do any errors in moving in the Vigenere cipher and if the alphabet I used was correct, the answer should be:
npaawyyhbnpyvxyehtsojfjgmxauobccaa
Unfortunately I am Italian so I don't know if the answer is reasonable (and I hope it does not contain any bad words :) ). If it is not maybe you should try rearrange the letters in order to form Finnish words. Otherwise you can try adding or subtracting 4 (the number of the question) to each letter and see if the result is reasonable.

Answer (score -2):

4

Cryptic code is 4

4th question also supports that

Also,
NFITJMDSMNFCVHMNMBSERFYWVELUEKCQSJ
AGOPXZ
1  7 15 16 24 26
6 , 8, 1, 8, 2
-2, 7,-7, 6

Comment: I'm not sure I understand what you're trying to say here. The cryptic message is "4"?